# I got 500 error while calling API in node js

Tags: node.js, postman

I'm new to in node js and it's my first API. I have create the node.js express project from it's official website and when I call any API from postman then it gives error like this.

```
ReferenceError: CircularJSON is not defined
```

I'm trying to print just request data into terminal.

In postman I have set headers which is as under.

```
Content-Type:application/json
```

And in row I have select JSON(application/json)

And my object is this.

```
{
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "password":"123456"
}
```

My node route code is :

```
 router.post('/login', function(req , res, next) {  
    console.log("Login req ::: " , CircularJSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send({status:1,message:"ok"});
 });
```

Comment: you might need to import it

Comment: You need to import CircularJSON via require

Comment: Thank for your reply it's helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add into js file .

```
var JsonCircular = require('json-circular');
```

And then try to print your data.

```
console.log("Data is : " , JsonCircular.stringify(req.body));
```

It will print your data which you passed in you postman API.

Comment: For that you need to run command npm install json-circular --save and then add this code @khushboo